# How to get Html.BeginForm to GET to correct MVC Route

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing

In my ASP.NET MVC application I have the following GET input field:

```
<% using (Html.BeginForm("Search", "Products", FormMethod.Get) { %>
   <input type="text" name="searchQuery" id="searchQuery" />
<% } %
```

I want this to go to the route:

```
routes.MapRoute("ProductSearchRoute", 
    "Products/Search/{searchQuery}/{pageNumber}", 
new { controller = "Products", action = "Search", pageNumber = 1 });
```

The problem is, it goes to /Products as query string, e.g. Products?searchQuery=Motoroil. How do I get it to use my ProductSearchRoute and instead form /Products/Search/Motoroil ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you're trying to dynamically alter the location the form posts to, based on the inputs of the form?

You'll need to use javascript for this, to alter the form's target attribute.  The BeginForm() is for rendering the form tag, which from an html perspective, is static.

Answer (score 1):

You could try:

```
<% using (Html.BeginRouteForm("ProductSearchRoute", FormMethod.Get)) %>
```

Kindness,

Dan

Comment: This is 1/2 way there. It still creates the querystring "?": http://localhost:8820/Products/Search/?searchQuery=test

Comment: Basically, how do I get it to understand that my input "searchQuery" corresponds to /Products/Search/{searchQuery} <-- put the value instead of {searchQuery}

Comment: I'm pretty sure there's no way to do this.  The HTML Helper methods render a form tag to the browser - but there's nothing that would alter the target attribute of the form based on user input that comes *after* the form is rendered.  You'll need to use javascript I think.

Comment: Hmm, yes I think you're right.. I need to see if I can do with with jQuery intercepting the submit.. arghh

Comment: /me defers to Womp; could not put it better :)

Comment: You *could* have an interim action method that took the querystring and Redirects to a prettier URL? eg /abc/xyz/?something=hij and redirect to /abc/xyz/hij

Comment: @Dan I wish I could do that with MapRoutes

Comment: I've not tried writing a route as such with the ? in it (interesting!); I'll give it a go a little later and see.

Comment: No dice; a juicy 500 page and URL cannot contain a ?. Short, informal but informative from the ASP.NET compiler ;)

Answer (score 1):

```
public ActionResult SearchQuery (string searchQuery)
{
    return RedirectToAction (searchQuery, "/Products/Search" );
}

public ActionResult Search (string searchQuery)
{
    return View();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As @Daniel Elliott suggested, use BeginRouteForm. To get your URL to generate properly, you have to set the routevalues with the same name defined in your route table.

```
@using (Html.BeginRouteForm("ProductSearchRoute", new { searchQuery= "my query", pageNumber = 1 })
{

}
```